# Rails Url_For Wrong Link Being Used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, spree

I am having an odd issue where sometimes on my production server, the url for function returns my server's IP and rails local storage instead of a AWS link.

I have correctly configured my storage settings but I am not for sure where else I need to look.

I am running rails 6.0.3 and spree commerce 4.1

Comment: Can you post the actual code that is causing issues?

Comment: `main_app.url_for(i.url(:product))` Literally just that, where i is a loop of products that have attachments. Nothing crazy which is why this is puzzling.

Comment: Do you have any caching?

Comment: Spree caches but other than that, no.